# How to make alias trailing with space hack works with parameter supplied

Tags: bash, command, alias, parameter, bash-expansion

I have two aliases `watchExpand` and `l`. I know that you can make bash expansion work with aliases by placing a trailing space like so:

```
alias watchExpand='watch '
```

`l` is aliased to `ls -larthiF --context`. So when I type the command `watchExpand l` it works like a charm.

However if I supply a parameter to `watchExpand` command, e.g.

```
watchExpand -n 1 l
```

My `l` alias no longer works. How can I get bash expansion after arguments?

Comment: aliases don't expand unless they're the first word in a line

Comment: [bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) says: "If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion"

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea, but if the question is: "how can I expand every parameter to an aliased command in case that parameter is also an alias?" is to make your aliased command (watchExpand) a function that loops over its parameters and does so manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the bad idea I *think* you're asking for:

```
function watchExpand() {
  e=""
  for param in $@
  do
    if alias $param >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
      exp=$(alias $param | cut -d= -f2| sed -e s/^\'// -e s/\'\$//)
      e+=" $exp"
    else
      e+=" $param"
    fi
  done
  watch $e
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Zsh has global aliases. You could do:

```bash
alias -g @l='ls -larthiF --context'
```

and then:

```
watch -n 1 @l
```

Note that `@` is not mandatory, but I use it to avoid having the global aliases invoked unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the solution with my way.

Firstly, i create a function called "addExpand" to add alias/fucntion easier if i want.

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/t$ type -a addExpand
addExpand is a function
addExpand () 
{ 
    echo -e "#!/bin/bash\nshopt -s expand_aliases\n. ~/.bash_aliases 2>/dev/null\n$1"' "$@"' | sudo tee /usr/bin/e_"$1";
    sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/e_"$1"
}
xb@dnxb:/tmp/t$ addExpand l
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
. ~/.bash_aliases 2>/dev/null
l "$@"
```

After i run `addExpand l`, alias `l` will created as an executable file named **/usr/bin/e_l** with following content:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/t$ cat /usr/bin/e_l
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
. ~/.bash_aliases 2>/dev/null
l "$@"
```

Now enjoy to use expand version of alias/function:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/t$ watch --color -n 1 e_l /tmp //works like a charm !!!
xb@dnxb:/tmp/t$
```

Note:

[1] `e_l`, prefix with 'e_' to imply it's expansion version of command.

[2] I feel too heavy to perform sourcing every seconds if run with `watch -n 1`. I might need to find a way to solve this problem.

[3] Another disadvantage is it doesn't resolve alias recursively.